# Feign client manually. Load balancer does not have available server for client

Tags: netflix-eureka, netflix-feign

I have two services registered with eureka. Service C calls service A. Service C is feign client. I want implement feign client manually. But I catch an exception:

> com.netflix.client.ClientException: Load balancer does not have
>   available server for client: service-test-a

Application class:

```
@EnableEurekaClient
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Feign interface:

```
@Component
public interface FeignService {
    @RequestLine("GET /")
    public String getServiceA();
}
```

Feign config:

```
@Configuration
@Import(FeignClientsConfiguration.class)
public class MyConfig {

}
```

Controller:

```
@RestController
public class Controller {

    private FeignService feignService;

    @Autowired
    public void Controller() {
        feignService = Feign.builder()
                .client(RibbonClient.create())
                .target(FeignService.class, "http://service-test-a");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/build", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getServiceC() {
        return feignService.getServiceA();
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Instead of creating a new `RibbonClient` why not use the bean that is already created?

Comment: I followed the official documentation https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign/tree/master/ribbon

Comment: I don't know which bean I should use. Could you tell me please?

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, there is no easy way of using **OpenFeign** with eureka. There is no guide or example for that. Also I guess that it may require some additional implementations and configuration.

Instead, please try to use **Spring Cloud Feign**. It provides full integration with eureka and ribbon without any additional implementation. You can use Spring Cloud Feign with just a few changes in your above code.

Please refer to [Spring Cloud Feign](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/spring-cloud-netflix.html#spring-cloud-feign)

Comment: Thank you. I saw it. But I would like to deal with the builder.

Comment: You can use builder with spring cloud feign.